# TS strict infer for type number

Tags: typescript

I want to infer the number type in the following function:

```
type Options = { count: number };

function foo<O extends Options>(options: O): O['count'] extends 3 ? 'x' : 'y' {}

foo({ count: 3 }) // x
foo({ count: 4 }) // y
```

Is there any way to do it without using `as const` or `count: 1 | 2 | 3 ...`?

Comment: Could you give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one more level of generic abstraction:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgHJQgD2AhQBM0oUBXAWwCMIAnKAXnOrvoD5moBvKAYyQUUwAFxQcAXwDcAWABQCgGbD+iVFCVIkUbLgJFSrWgwA0sfYRJk469Ng4cAFEnjJ04mAEpPAbQDkgsLA-gC6vApQUPQQwBT0KFCudmgAdEEicvKSCsraTnwZYlAAzFCSXlAA9FWleUgFAkIi4gAs5ZU1UK1AA)

```ts
type Options<N extends number = number> = { count: N };

function foo <N extends number, O extends Options<N>>(options: O): O['count'] {
  return options.count;
}

foo({ count: 3 }) // 3
foo({ count: 4 }) // 4
```

Comment: But now each function that uses this interface needs to do the same. I'm looking for something seamless/general.

Comment: @undefined I'm not sure I understand your meaning. Can you clarify? The default type parameter for `Options` allows you to use it in a non-generic way (and the resulting type in that case would be `{ count: number }`).

Comment: I mean each function that needs to use this interface, foo1(options), foo2(options), needs to do the same, right?

Comment: @undefined The only time you'd need the extra generic is when you need to infer a number literal.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I'm using this interface in multiple functions.